# How to add a button to the right of navigationview item?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, onclicklistener, android-navigationview, itemgroup

I'm trying to add a button to the right of a group items, witch will be shown only when I press long click on the item.

Like in this example:

[image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWVf8.jpg)

How to do this?

Comment: You need to create custom navigation drawer. Please google it and you will find many tutorials. If you dont find let me know.

Comment: I founded some tutorials, but actually is to much code just for showing a delete icon in the right of an item.How to delete an item whitout needing to show that icon, but still inform the user about what is he doing?